# union results with the same conditions

Tags: sqlite

I have a `inventory` table in my `sqlite` database which contains columns `category`, `name`, and `count`. I want to filter out the rows with `count` less than 2, and put another `category` row before all the other data in the with the category so that it's easier to store them in tree views in GUIs.

My data in the table is:

```
category    name        count     
----------  ----------  ----------
fruit       apple       4         
fruit       banana      3         
fruit       peach       2         
meat        pork        1         
meat        beef        1         
vegetable   spinach     5         
vegetable   carrot      2
```

and what I do is:

```
SELECT category, '', 0 FROM inventory
UNION
SELECT category, name, count FROM inventory
    WHERE category IN
        (SELECT category FROM inventory
         UNION
         SELECT category FROM inventory)
    AND count > 1;
```

and what I got is:

```
category    ''          0         
----------  ----------  ----------
fruit                   0         
fruit       apple       4         
fruit       banana      3         
fruit       peach       2         
meat                    0         
vegetable               0         
vegetable   carrot      2         
vegetable   spinach     5
```

And actually what I want in this case is without the `meat` row.

I think the problem is that the `WHERE` clause only applies to the `SELECT` after the first `UNION`. But how can I also put the condition on the first `SELECT`? Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compound queries are built from complete queries (except for ORDER BY).

You should use UNION without ALL only if you actually want to remove duplicates.

You need ORDER BY to sort the header rows into the correct position.

```
SELECT category, NULL AS name, NULL AS count
FROM inventory
GROUP BY category
HAVING max(count) > 1

UNION ALL

SELECT category, name, count
FROM inventory
WHERE count > 1

ORDER BY category, name;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great! So the part before the `UNION ALL` is to get all the category rows whose items' maximum count is greater than 1, and the second half is to get all the item rows whose count is greater than 1, and then combine the results and sort them. Is that right?

Comment: Yes (you can just try these queries).